# STRFTIME returns Null

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to filter by **month** in Sqlite, but the `STRFTIME` function returns `Null`.

The dates seem to be in a standard format.

```
SELECT arrival_date a, 
       departure_date d, 
       strftime('%m', arrival_date) m 
  FROM table
```

Returns (for example):

```
 13/02/2015, 15/02/2015, Null
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Use the proper tag and not in question title

Comment: Please provide sample data.  If the dates are in the standard format, then the month should be valid.  You seem to have an invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

`strftime()`, and all other sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), will return `null` if given an argument in a format that they don't understand. `DD/MM/YYYY` formatted dates like `13/02/2015` are not an understood format. The complete list is in the documentation, but if storing just a date as a string, `YYYY-MM-DD` is what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `strftime` function for SQLite is intended to be used to parse a text date, perform some manipulation (e.g. adding some days), and then returning an output date string.  If you just want to *extract* the numerical month component, then use `substr`:

```
SELECT
    arrival_date a, 
    departure_date d,
    substr(arrival_date, 4, 2) m
FROM table;
```