# format 24-hour query sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this data frame.

```
index   id                      created_at
0       1205913004379910149     Sat Dec 14 18:10:39 +0000 2019
1       1205912996091813888     Sat Dec 14 18:10:37 +0000 2019
2       1205912994988711936     Sat Dec 14 18:10:37 +0000 2019`
```

i need extract the hour in the format %H:%M:%S

This is my code

```
query = '''
SELECT id as "id tweet", strftime('%H:%M:%S', created_at) as "hour"
FROM tab_created
'''
```

But, the output is

```
index   id tweet                    hour
0       1205913004379910149         none
1       1205912996091813888         none
2       1205912994988711936         none
```

i need something like

```
index   id tweet                    hour
0       1205913004379910149         18:10:39
1       1205912996091813888         18:10:37
2       1205912994988711936         18:10:37
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56596047/strftime-returns-null) post, it might help you

Answer (score 0):

The function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) recognizes dates only in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and similar.
 
So your format is not applicable to `strftime()`. 
 
What you can do, if the format is always like `Sat Dec 14 18:10:39 +0000 2019` is use the function `substr()`:

```
SELECT id as "id tweet", substr(created_at, 12, 8) as "hour"
FROM tab_created
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5EmJeWVYD9fUf6E1di8aAS/2).
Results:

```
| id tweet            | hour     |
| ------------------- | -------- |
| 1205913004379910149 | 18:10:39 |
| 1205912996091813888 | 18:10:37 |
| 1205912994988711936 | 18:10:37 |
```